# Is it possible to scale the entire title page?

Tags: graphics, titles, scaling

I am creating a booklet which has now a rather fancy title page with various fonts, font sizes, horizontal and vertical spacings, images embedded etc. It looks nice, but somehow the margins (let me clarify: the visible white space) around the titlepage are too big, and I would like to zoom in the entire page just a little bit so that it would look more nicely. Is there a way to do this? (Obviously I don't want to start changing the sizes of the fonts and pictures one by one...).

I was trying to make work `\scalebox{}{}` from the `\graphicx` package which I used earlier successfully to make tables bigger, but this time it seems to be failing.

Here is a MNWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[draft]{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\title{Test title}
\author{Test author}
\date{\today}
%\scalebox{2}{%
\clearpage\maketitle
%\scalebox{2}{%
\begin{center}
\includegraphics{test.jpg}
\end{center}
\scalebox{2}{%

Some additional text}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why don't you use `\newgeometry` from thethe `geometry` package to change the margins locally?

Comment: @Bernard I will need to check this, but I want to enlarge the text and pictures. Shrinking the margins would mean that the same text of the same size will be streched out to a larger space. This is *not* what I want.

Comment: this is a bit of a nuisance, but you could set the title page separately to a pdf file, with the current dimensions, crop the resulting page with `pdfcrop`, then drop it into the main document as a graphic, scaling it as desired.

Comment: @barbarabeeton wouldn't this import-export thing have heavy impact on the quality of the pictures?

Comment: if your page contains nothing but (embedded) fonts and vector graphics -- **no bitmaps** -- it should scale just as cleanly as the rest of the file when you look at it in a pdf viewer or print it.  this is essentially the same as what you're doing with `\scalebox`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, I first save the original geometry, Then, I place the page one contents in a saved `\vbox`, then change the geometry and present a scaled version of the box.  Finally, I restore the original geometry for the next page.

EDITED to apply `\centering` to `\scalebox`, as noted by OP.

Note: I employ `\savegeometry{}` and `\loadgeometry{}`, but as runartrollet notes, for this simple case, I could have just used a `\restoregeometry`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[pass]{geometry}
\usepackage[draft]{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\title{Test title}
\author{Test author}
\date{\today}
\savegeometry{ORIG}
\setbox0=\vbox{
\clearpage\maketitle
\begin{center}
\includegraphics{test.jpg}
\end{center}
Some additional text \lipsum[1-2]}
%
\newgeometry{margin=1cm}
\thispagestyle{empty}
{\centering\scalebox{1.49}{\box0}\par}
\clearpage
\loadgeometry{ORIG}
\lipsum[3-5]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This looks promising, I will need to check this.

Comment: Is it necessary to save the geometry? wouldn't simply `\restoregeometry` suffice?

Comment: @runartrollet Yes, I believe you are correct.  My extra step results from my rusty use of the package.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes I'm rusty too. Didn't know there was a `savegeometry`-macro, really.

Comment: For whatever strange reasons I needed to surround the `\scalebox{}{}` call by a `\begin{center}...\end{center}` environment.

Comment: @Matsmath That is not unreasonable.  I had manually tweaked the left/right margins, and scale size to match, but in general, the centering approach is more foolproof. I have edited my answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 1):

Using `\scalebox` is not always that pretty. Although you said that you didn't want to change the font for every field, this is exactly what I suggest you do. It keeps the font sizes consistent through your documents, and for the title, there really isn't that many fields. Have a look at [Wikisbooks' article on font sizing](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Fonts#Sizing_text) for the different macros for the sizes. If the sizes are not big enough for your needs, have a look at the commented out code.

Please forgive me if you already know that you can size fonts this way, and I am not really helping you with your question directly. This is more advice on a different way of doing it, keeping it more consistent.

Also, you might not want to use the `center` environment as it produces some extra whitespace. Use `\centering`instead.

Use the `geometry` package to edit the margins, either for the title page only, and restore it after, or for the whole document.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[draft]{graphicx}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\newgeometry{left=1.5cm,right=1.5cm}
\title{\Huge Test title}
%\title{\scalebox{4}{\huge Test title}}
\author{\LARGE Test author}
\date{\Large\today}
\maketitle
\begin{figure}[hbt]
  \centering
\includegraphics[scale=2]{test.jpg}
\end{figure}


Some additional text
\clearpage
\restoregeometry
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I want to try out many different kind of margins, so I think multiple resize for the fonts and vertical spaces would be necessary which I want to avoid completely.